# How does pandas take the max of strings in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max

Im wondering why taking a max from a dataframe column of strings throws no error..

E.g. consider the following pandas dataframe:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'names': ['Tim', 'Sebby', 'Max', 'Julia', 'Troy']})
```

When taking the max of the column,

```
df_test.max()
```

it gives me

> Troy

I don't understand how this works? How can pandas take the max of strings?

Comment: Please post code not pics.

Comment: Looks like lexicographically

Comment: To answer your question  [Lexicographical_order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)